# I want to create separate jvm for separate classes when testing with testng. Iit gives ExecutionException Error occurred in starting fork error

Tags: java, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to create separate jvm for separate classes when testing with testng. Iit gives ExecutionException Error occurred in starting fork error.

Here is the code.

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>             
              <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testplan/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
            <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
            <workingDirectory>${my.client}</workingDirectory>
          </configuration>
    </plugin>
```